# Why, when split binary, Auto Focus doesn't work anymore?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

When export APK without split binary, work perfectly.
When choose "split binary" ( apk and obb files ), auto focus doesn't work!!
I'm using Unity 4.5.0 and Vuforia 3.0.9.

I add this line to Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml to strengthen the existing autofocus:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But, nothing happen when split...

Here the code added to ARCamera to debug and try to force autofocus:

```
if(CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO))
{
    Debug.Log("Unity: FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO"); // When NOT split, works fine
    mFocusMode = CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO;
    mContinousAFSupported = true;​
}else{
    Debug.LogError("Unity: could not switch to continuous autofocus"); // When split, ERROR!
    mContinousAFSupported = false;
    mFocusMode = CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_NORMAL;​
}
```

Anybody has this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is not autofocus, the problem is Vuforia and OBB file expansion.

The solution i receive on Unity forum, by a friend that have the same problem and help me.

So i will left all links here to help everybody that will be problems like me on Vuforia 3.x, OK and Unity 4.x. The new versions of, i dont test yet.

Heres the link.
My friend help: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/why-when-split-binary-auto-focus-doesnt-work-anymore.309233/

Vuforia doc for OBB: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-handle-large-android-apps

How to handle it: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/dataset-does-not-exist-error-when-using-unity-4-android
This last one HELP ME A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

I was just browsing through the new update from Vuforia and I stumbled across something that might be the answer to your question.

So, with the new Vuforia 4, they've released [**Download Calibration Application**](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/beta) under the `BETA` tab that I'm sure does exactly what you're asking for, ie. it calibrates the camera of the device accordingly.

It is still in `BETA` so check it out and let me know if it works.